# Data-binding for a simple slider with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have developed a simple UI slider directive that has an isolated scope. It also supports registering a `change` property that is fired when the value of the slider changed. The `change` property would usually call a function of a parent scope with the slider value from the isolated scope, like this:

`change="onValueChanged(theValue)"`

where `change` is an attribute, `onValueChanged` is a function declared in a parent controller and `theValue` is the current value of the element that is only declared in the isolated scope.

How can I `$eval` this correctly? In the slider's `link` function I can call `$scope.$eval(attrs.change)` but `$scope.onValueChanged` is not defined. The isolated scope did not inherit from its parent. At the same time, `$scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.change)` correctly calls the `onValueChanged` function, but `theValue` will not be set because it is isolated in the child scope. Since the `change` property can reference any number of parent scope properties, I cannot explicitly declare them in the isolated scope.

How can I `eval` the `change` property so that all variables from the different scopes will be present? Is there a way to force the isolated scope to inherit from its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that there were several small issues with my approach. My final slider looks a little like this:

```
/**
 * A jquery-UI slider with databinding.
 * @see http://jsfiddle.net/vNfsm/50/
 */
app.directive('slider', function() {
    var linkFun = function($scope, element, attrs) {
        var $slider = jQuery(element);
        var option = attrs;
        var readIntOption = function(key, option) {
            if (option[key]) {
                option[key] = parseInt(option[key]);
            }
        };

        // read default options
        readIntOption("min", option);
        readIntOption("max", option);
        readIntOption("step", option);

        // add `value` and `change` properties to slider for data-binding
        option = jQuery.extend({
            change: function(event, ui) {
                if (!event.which) return;   // only trigger on UI events
                if (ui.value != $scope.valueModel) {
                    // update value
                    $scope.valueModel = ui.value;

                    // update the value of the variable that is bound to `valueModel`
                    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }

                    // raise callback
                    if ($scope.valueChanged) {
                        $scope.valueChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, option);

        // data binding in the other direction
        $scope.$watch("valueModel", function(val) {
            if ($scope.valueModel != $slider.slider("value")) {
                // update slider value
                // this will not raise the `change` event above
                $slider.slider("value", $scope.valueModel);
            }
        });

        // create slider
        $slider.slider(option);
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        template: '<div />',
        scope: {
            valueModel: '=',
            valueChanged: '&'
        },
        link: linkFun
    };
});
```

This is an example instance of a slider:

```
<slider
    value-model="ratingsOwn[category.categoryId]"
    value-changed="onRatingsChange(ratingsOwn[category.categoryId])"
    range="min"
    step="{{category.valueStep}}"
    min="{{category.valueMin}}"
    max="{{category.valueMax}}"></slider>
```

These were the issues I had to fix:

1. **Avoid accessing isolated scope variables from the outside**. Since the isolated value model is actually bound to some variable in the parent scope, simply use that instead. This way, there is no mixing of scopes, and things become a whole lot simpler.
2. When binding variables, make sure to **propagate changes** to all bound models, by calling `$apply` or similar, **before** calling any hook callbacks (e.g. `value-changed`, in this case).
3. As @Rafal points out, `$eval` can be avoided by simply using uni-directional data-binding (`&`) and treating the `$scope`'s property as a function (that is how `value-changed` works in the above example).
4. Be careful when setting up data-binding to **avoid infinite loops**. In this case, the `$watch` binding will be triggered by the UI (by checking `event.which`), but vice versa is avoided, to break the loop. When the value variable is updated programatically, the slider will be updated but its `change` event will not be triggered.
5. Do not mess with `transclude` if you want multiple directive instances in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use eval.
When defining a directive with an isolate scope you can use one way binding like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
return{
//...
    scope:{
       functionToCall: '&'
    }
//...
}}
```

When your change event is fired simply call the function in the link function like this:

```
scope.functionToCall({change:changeVal});
```

edit:
When using the directive pass in the function from the controller like this:

```
<my-directive function-to-call="functionInController(change)"></my-directive>
```

Comment: What is `change` in `functionInController(change)`?